# Generics and type inference in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am reading generics chapter in "Thinking in Java 4th edition" and there is an example:

```
class Fruit{}
class Apple extends Fruit {}
```

...

```
static <T> void writeExact(List<T> list, T item) {
            list.add(item);
    }

    static List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<>();
        static List<Fruit> fruit = new ArrayList<>();

        static void f1() {
            writeExact(apples, new Apple());
            // writeExact(fruit, new Apple()); // Error:
            // Incompatible types: found Fruit, required Apple
        }

        static <T> void writeWithWildcard(List<? super T> list, T item) {
            list.add(item);
        }

        static void f2() {
            writeWithWildcard(apples, new Apple());
            writeWithWildcard(fruit, new Apple());
        }
```

Those commented line, where error is indicated, doesn't produce any error at all both in 6 and 7 Java. It seems weird for me, as `writeExact` method accepts only exact type of parameter. So why does it work? And since it works what is a purpose of supertype wildcards?

**edit**

so i got it and want to clarify one more thing:
who is the boss in type inference with wildcards? return type, first parameter, second parameter, ... . I mean that if SomeClass.<**Fruit**>method(...) is not specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because the `T` in `writeExact` is a type variable on the method itself. Look, it's right there before the void return type:

```
static <T> void writeExact(List<T> list, T item)
```

That means that whenever you call it, its `T` takes on the type needed to accept its arguments, as long as there is one. You can call it with any list and an object that would fit in that list.

Perhaps it makes it clearer to explicitly give the type argument, rather than letting the compiler infer it (you need to use the class's name to do this for a static method; i will assume it is `MyClass`):

```
        MyClass.<Apple>writeExact(apples, new Apple());
        MyClass.<Fruit>writeExact(fruit, new Apple());
```

In the second call, `T` has the value `Fruit`, which means the first argument must be a `List<Fruit>`, which it is, and the second must be a `Fruit`, which it is, because `Apple` is a subtype of `Fruit`.

The rules for implicitly assigning type arguments are given in [section 15.12.2.7 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.7). At least, i think they are; it's not exactly an easy read.

I would guess that the code in the book is not exactly the same as the code you give above. If it is, then it it definitely incorrect, and you should write to Mr Eckel and tell him.

Comment: the code is exactly the same, I can share with you the pdf that I'm reading now :). What is the purpose of supertype wildcard in that example?

Comment: I think the whole example may actually be complete rubbish. Bounded wildcards do have their uses, but this code does not demonstrate one! Seriously, check the errata for the book to see if this is covered, and if not, write and ask the author.

Comment: I believe the correct syntax is `this.<Apple>writeExact(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
static <T> void writeExact(List<T> list, T item) {
            list.add(item);
    }
```

would accept (List of Applies,Apple or List of Fruits, Fruit or List of Applles, Fruit(as Fruit is the subtype of apple)) because you declared it with parameterized types **T**.

Comment: and so what? unless do they have not to be the same(in list and in second parameter)?

Comment: T should be same as you declared the generic type in your method singnature before void <T>

Comment: my question is about why can I pass to method such types as `List<Fruit>` and `Apple`

Comment: you could pass List<Fruit> and Apple as Apple is the subtype of Apple. but not the other way around

Comment: so, is it a mistake in the book?